# Msys2 mingw built libcurl with openssl, but https unsupported

Tags: c++, https, libcurl

I need to use libcurl with https in my project, so I've built zlib, openssl and libcurl (with `mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib`) successfully. But after I copied `include` `libcurl.a` `libcurldll.a` `libcurl.dll` to my project folder, sent a `GET` request to `https://www.google.com` it failed with error `Unsupported protocol`

My `OPENSSL_PATH` and `ZLIB_PATH` in my `lib/Makefile.m32` `src/Makefile.m32` are:
`ZLIB_PATH = ../../zlib-1.2.8`
`OPENSSL_PATH = /c/OpenSSL`

and the build log:

```
Compeador@DESKTOP-QCSNUGN MSYS /e/programming/c/lib/curl-7.74.0
$ mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -C lib -f Makefile.m32 CFG=mingw32-ssl-zlib
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/programming/c/lib/curl-7.74.0/lib'
gcc -I. -I../include -I"C:/OpenSSL/include" -I"../../zlib-1.2.8"  -g -O2 -Wall -W -fno-strict-aliasing -m32 -DBUILDING_LIBCURL -DUSE_OPENSSL -DHAVE_OPENSSL_PKCS12_H -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_ZLIB_H -c altsvc.c -o altsvc.o
gcc ......
ar cru libcurl.a altsvc.o amigaos.o asyn-ares.o asyn-thread.o base64.o conncache.o connect.o content_encoding.o cookie.o curl_addrinfo.o curl_ctype.o curl_des.o curl_endian.o curl_fnmatch.o curl_get_line.o curl_gethostname.o curl_gssapi.o curl_memrchr.o curl_multibyte.o curl_ntlm_core.o curl_ntlm_wb.o curl_path.o curl_range.o curl_rtmp.o curl_sasl.o curl_sspi.o curl_threads.o dict.o dotdot.o easy.o escape.o file.o fileinfo.o formdata.o ftp.o url.o ftplistparser.o getenv.o getinfo.o gopher.o hash.o hmac.o hostasyn.o hostcheck.o hostip.o hostip4.o hostip6.o hostsyn.o http.o http2.o http_chunks.o http_digest.o http_negotiate.o http_ntlm.o http_proxy.o idn_win32.o if2ip.o imap.o inet_ntop.o inet_pton.o krb5.o ldap.o llist.o md4.o md5.o memdebug.o mime.o mprintf.o mqtt.o multi.o netrc.o non-ascii.o nonblock.o openldap.o parsedate.o pingpong.o pop3.o progress.o psl.o doh.o rand.o rename.o rtsp.o select.o sendf.o setopt.o sha256.o share.o slist.o smb.o smtp.o socketpair.o socks.o socks_gssapi.o socks_sspi.o speedcheck.o splay.o strcase.o strdup.o strerror.o strtok.o strtoofft.o system_win32.o telnet.o tftp.o timeval.o transfer.o urlapi.o version.o warnless.o wildcard.o x509asn1.o dynbuf.o version_win32.o easyoptions.o easygetopt.o hsts.o vauth/cleartext.o vauth/cram.o vauth/digest.o vauth/digest_sspi.o vauth/krb5_gssapi.o vauth/krb5_sspi.o vauth/ntlm.o vauth/ntlm_sspi.o vauth/oauth2.o vauth/spnego_gssapi.o vauth/spnego_sspi.o vauth/vauth.o vtls/bearssl.o vtls/gskit.o vtls/gtls.o vtls/keylog.o vtls/mbedtls.o vtls/mbedtls_threadlock.o vtls/mesalink.o vtls/nss.o vtls/openssl.o vtls/schannel.o vtls/schannel_verify.o vtls/sectransp.o vtls/vtls.o vtls/wolfssl.o vquic/ngtcp2.o vquic/quiche.o vquic/vquic.o vssh/libssh.o vssh/libssh2.o vssh/wolfssh.o
ranlib libcurl.a
strip -g libcurl.a
windres --include-dir=../include -DDEBUGBUILD=0 -O coff -F pe-i386 -i libcurl.rc -o libcurl.res
gcc   -s -m32 -shared -o libcurl.dll \
-Wl,--output-def,libcurl.def,--out-implib,libcurldll.a \
altsvc.o amigaos.o asyn-ares.o asyn-thread.o base64.o conncache.o connect.o content_encoding.o cookie.o curl_addrinfo.o curl_ctype.o curl_des.o curl_endian.o curl_fnmatch.o curl_get_line.o curl_gethostname.o curl_gssapi.o curl_memrchr.o curl_multibyte.o curl_ntlm_core.o curl_ntlm_wb.o curl_path.o curl_range.o curl_rtmp.o curl_sasl.o curl_sspi.o curl_threads.o dict.o dotdot.o easy.o escape.o file.o fileinfo.o formdata.o ftp.o url.o ftplistparser.o getenv.o getinfo.o gopher.o hash.o hmac.o hostasyn.o hostcheck.o hostip.o hostip4.o hostip6.o hostsyn.o http.o http2.o http_chunks.o http_digest.o http_negotiate.o http_ntlm.o http_proxy.o idn_win32.o if2ip.o imap.o inet_ntop.o inet_pton.o krb5.o ldap.o llist.o md4.o md5.o memdebug.o mime.o mprintf.o mqtt.o multi.o netrc.o non-ascii.o nonblock.o openldap.o parsedate.o pingpong.o pop3.o progress.o psl.o doh.o rand.o rename.o rtsp.o select.o sendf.o setopt.o sha256.o share.o slist.o smb.o smtp.o socketpair.o socks.o socks_gssapi.o socks_sspi.o speedcheck.o splay.o strcase.o strdup.o strerror.o strtok.o strtoofft.o system_win32.o telnet.o tftp.o timeval.o transfer.o urlapi.o version.o warnless.o wildcard.o x509asn1.o dynbuf.o version_win32.o easyoptions.o easygetopt.o hsts.o vauth/cleartext.o vauth/cram.o vauth/digest.o vauth/digest_sspi.o vauth/krb5_gssapi.o vauth/krb5_sspi.o vauth/ntlm.o vauth/ntlm_sspi.o vauth/oauth2.o vauth/spnego_gssapi.o vauth/spnego_sspi.o vauth/vauth.o vtls/bearssl.o vtls/gskit.o vtls/gtls.o vtls/keylog.o vtls/mbedtls.o vtls/mbedtls_threadlock.o vtls/mesalink.o vtls/nss.o vtls/openssl.o vtls/schannel.o vtls/schannel_verify.o vtls/sectransp.o vtls/vtls.o vtls/wolfssl.o vquic/ngtcp2.o vquic/quiche.o vquic/vquic.o vssh/libssh.o vssh/libssh2.o vssh/wolfssh.o libcurl.res -L"C:/OpenSSL/lib" -lssl -lcrypto  -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -L"../../zlib-1.2.8" -lz -lwldap32 -lws2_32
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/programming/c/lib/curl-7.74.0/lib'
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -C src -f Makefile.m32 CFG=mingw32-ssl-zlib
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/programming/c/lib/curl-7.74.0/src'
windres --include-dir=../include -O coff -DCURL_EMBED_MANIFEST -F pe-i386 -i curl.rc -o curl.res
gcc -I. -I../include -I../lib -I"C:/OpenSSL/include" -I"../../zlib-1.2.8"  -g -O2 -Wall -W -fno-strict-aliasing -m32 -DCURL_STATICLIB -DUSE_OPENSSL -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_ZLIB_H -c slist_wc.c
gcc ......
rm -f  curl.exe
gcc   -s -m32 -static -o curl.exe curl.res slist_wc.o tool_binmode.o tool_bname.o tool_cb_dbg.o tool_cb_hdr.o tool_cb_prg.o tool_cb_rea.o tool_cb_see.o tool_cb_wrt.o tool_cfgable.o tool_convert.o tool_dirhie.o tool_doswin.o tool_easysrc.o tool_filetime.o tool_formparse.o tool_getparam.o tool_getpass.o tool_help.o tool_helpers.o tool_homedir.o tool_hugehelp.o tool_libinfo.o tool_main.o tool_metalink.o tool_msgs.o tool_operate.o tool_operhlp.o tool_panykey.o tool_paramhlp.o tool_parsecfg.o tool_progress.o tool_strdup.o tool_setopt.o tool_sleep.o tool_urlglob.o tool_util.o tool_vms.o tool_writeout.o tool_writeout_json.o tool_xattr.o strtoofft.o nonblock.o warnless.o curl_ctype.o curl_multibyte.o version_win32.o dynbuf.o -L../lib -lcurl -L"C:/OpenSSL/lib" -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -L"../../zlib-1.2.8" -lz -lwldap32 -lws2_32
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/programming/c/lib/curl-7.74.0/src'
```

and my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

size_t CurlStrWCallback(char* content, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata){
    auto total = size*nmemb;
    ((std::string*)userdata)->append((char*)content, total);
    return total;
}

int main(){
    auto curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL) != CURLE_OK){
        std::cout << "Fail to init curl\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if(curl){
        std::string buffer;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlStrWCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
        auto res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK){
            std::cout << "failed to perform request: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << '\n';
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Response:\n" << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

output: `failed to perform request: Unsupported protocol`

meanwhlie I also tried to run `libcurl/src/curl.exe https://www.google.com -k` and it sucessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to compile all source in the same fashion I use in Linux: `./configure && make && make install`
here are the commands I use:

- zlib:

  1. `./configure`
  2. `make && make install`
- openssl:

  1. `./configure --prefix=$PWD/dist no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 shared mingw` (or `mingw64` for 64 bits)
  2. `make && make install`
- libcurl:

  1. `./configure --prefix=$PWD/dist --with-zlib=PATH_TO_COMPILED_ZLIB --with-ssl=PATH_TO_COMPILED_OPENSSL --host=i686-w64-mingw32` (or `x86_64-w64-mingw32` for 64 bits)
  2. `make && make install`